# Editing the head element on an old blog platform on a post-by-post basis. Is this impossible or am I missing something?

Tags: header, blogs, head, movabletype

Sorry for being a total rookie.

I am trying to help my professor implement this advice:

> Either as a courtesy to Forbes or a favor to yourself, you may want to include the rel="canonical" link element on your cross-posts. To do this, on the content you want to take the backseat in search engines, you add  in the head of the page. The URL should be for the content you want to be favored by search engines. Otherwise, search engines see duplicate content, grow confused, and then get upset. You can read more about the canonical tag here: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/canonical-link-tag/. Have a great day!

The problem is I am having trouble figuring out how to edit the head element on a post-by-post basis. We are currently on a super old blogging platform (Movable Type 3.2 from 2005), so maybe it is not possible. But I'd like to know if that is likely the reason, so I'm not missing out on a workaround.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing much about your installation, I'll give a general description, and hopefully it matches what you see and helps.

In Movable Type, each blog has a "Design" section where you can see and edit the templates for the blog. On this page, the templates that are published once are listed under "Index Templates," and the templates published multiple times, once per entry, per category, etc., are listed under "Archive Templates."

There probably is an archive template called "Entry" (could be renamed) publishing to a path like `category/sub-category/entry-basename.php`. This is the main template that publishes each entry. Click on this to open the template editor.

This template could be an entire HTML document, or it might have "includes" that look like `<MTInclude module="">` or `<$mt:Include module=""$>` (MT supports varying tag styles.).

You may find there is an included module that contains the `<head>` content, or it might just be right in that template. To "follow" the includes and see those templates, there should be links on the side of the included templates.

Once you find the `<head>` content, you can add a canonical link tag like this:

```
<mt:IfArchiveType type="Individual">
  <mt:If tag="EntryPermalink">
<link rel="canonical" href="<$mt:EntryPermalink$>" />
  </mt:If>
</mt:IfArchiveType>
```

Depending on your needs, you might want to customize this to output a specific URL structure for other types of content, like category listings. The above will just take care of telling search engines the preferred URL for each entry.

Comment: using <mt:If tag="EntryPermalink"> is not very sensible, as an entry always have Permalink. Better to use some unused field, such as Extended text or keywords for this. if no such field exists, use a plugin such as moredata or custom fields.

Comment: Hi Schmuel, I don't remember the exact reason for this code now, but I am pretty sure it was to avoid some sort of error when it was included in a sitewide header. The purpose was simply to make sure it outputs only on entries, not on system (.cgi) pages or anything else.

Comment: According to my notes, it was to make sure it didn't show up on Pages, and only on Entries. I didn't test to see if it was necessary though!

Answer (score 0):

@Charlie: may be I'm missing something, but your solution basically places a canonical link on each entry to… itself, which is a no-no for search engines (the link should point to *another* page that's considered the canonical one).

@user2359284 you need a way to define the canonical entry for those which need this link. As Shmuel suggested, either reuse an unused field or a custom field plugin. Then you simply add that link in the header in the proper archive template that outputs your notes. In the hypothesis that the Entry template includes the same header as other templates, and, say, you're using the Keywords field to set the URL, then the following code should work (the mt:IfArchiveType test simply ensures it's output in the proper context, which you don't need if your Entry template has its own code for the header):

```
<mt:IfArchiveType type="Individual">
  <link rel="canonical" href="<$mt:EntryKeywords$>" />
</mt:IfArchiveType>
```